# array outside of loop changing (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void reverse(int[] arr)
    {
        int[] a= arr;
        int index=a.length-1;
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            System.out.println(ArrayUtil.toString(a));
            if (index>=0){
                arr[index]=a[i];
                index--;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, I'm trying to reverse the order of the elements in a given array. I declare another temporary array "a" that's the same as the given array. However, when going through the loop to reverse the order or elements, somehow the array "a" is also being changed. I don't see how this is possible. int[] arr in this case was [14,2,19,3,15,22,18,7] and the end result is [14,2,19,3,3,19,2,14] for both []arr and []a. Help would be really appreciated, thank you.

Also, I'm new to this forum, so I'm sorry if I didn't follow proper format

THANK YOU VERY MUCH for everyone who contributed! Amazing and fast responses!

Comment: _"somehow the array "a" is also being changed."_ What do you think `int[] a= arr;` does ?

Comment: It *is* the same array. You set it so when you declare `a`. If you want the same length new array, do `new int[arr.length]`.

Comment: This is called Pointer aliasing, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), it's caused because both `a` and `arr` point to the same memory location. So when one changes so does the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any modifications to `arr` will change `a`, and same thing vice versa, because they are references to the same array. You need to completely copy the array if you want two independent arrays:

```
int[] a = new int[arr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) a[i] = arr[i];
```

Or using `System.arrayCopy`:

```
int[] a = new int[arr.length];
System.arraycopy(arr, 0, a, 0, a.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
int[] a = new int[arr.length]
System.arraycopy( arr, 0, a, 0, arr.length);
```

to copy the actual elements inside and not the reference of the array. (Copying the reference means that both `a` and `arr` will refer to the same object, so any change to `a` is also a change to `arr`. This happens for all objects, as opposed to just primitives that are copied by value)

Answer (score 1):

Change algorithm for this. Even if you will fix your code, to make it working, you will use additional memory for it. Better use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++){
            int tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
            a[a.length - i - 1] = tmp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually with

```
int[] a= arr;
```

the same array's reference is given to array a.
And when you reversely assign values to arr, these values are actually being placed from the end of a
in reverse order. So at the end you get **symmetric** array